# Combinations in Scala, Need help in arriving at generic code without adding new functions

Tags: scala, recursion, combinations

I am trying to build a scala object that finds combinations for the given list.
Mathematical Notation: nc3 (ncr)
Example:

input :  `List("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")`

output: `List(abc, abd, abe, abf, acd, ace, acf, ade, adf, aef, bcd, bce, bcf, bde, bdf, bef, cde, cdf, cef, def)`

I have come up with this below object and logic however,

1. I see that this approach is not right because i have to add more functions as my r increases and the number of functions linearly increases with r (here r being 3).
2. All i have done is just coded the imperative style of three for loops in three functions.
3. Is there anyway these functions can be merged so that they are functional and should not have to repeat. By this way the object works for any value of r (ncr) without the need to add new functions.

ie; i can give input of nc4, nc5 without the need to add new functions.

```
object combinations_functionals {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val list = List("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
    println(function(list))
  }

  def function(x: List[String]): List[String] = {
    def fun(x: List[String], y: List[String]): List[String] = x match {
      case Nil => y.reverse
      case x :: xs => {
        fun(xs, function1(xs, x) ::: y)
      }
    }
    fun(x, Nil)
  }

  def function1(x: List[String], a: String): List[String] = {
    def fun1(x: List[String], y: List[String]): List[String] = x match {
      case Nil => y
      case x :: xs => {
        fun1(xs, function2(xs, a + x) ::: y)
      }
    }
    fun1(x, Nil)
  }

  def function2(x: List[String], b: String): List[String] = {
    def fun2(x: List[String], y: List[String]): List[String] = x match {
      case Nil => y
      case x :: xs => fun2(xs, b + x :: y)
    }
    fun2(x, Nil)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you don't want to use `combinations`?

```
List("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f").combinations(3).map(_.mkString)
// result: Iterator[String] = List(abc, abd, abe, abf, acd, ace, acf, ade, adf, aef, bcd, bce, bcf, bde, bdf, bef, cde, cdf, cef, def)
```

---

OK, so if you need to roll your own, would this work?

```
def combos(level: Int, lst: List[String], acc: String = ""): List[String] = {
  if (lst.isEmpty)
    Nil
  else if (level < 2)
    (acc + lst.head) :: combos(level, lst.tail, acc)
  else
    combos(level-1, lst.tail, acc + lst.head) ::: combos(level, lst.tail, acc)
}
```

Usage:

```
combos(4, List("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))
// res0: List[String] = List(abcd, abce, abde, acde, bcde)
```

Comment: yes, Thanks for checking. I do not want to use combinations, I am trying to construct an object or function that provides combinations.

Comment: Yes thanks a lot, this one works fine, thanks a lot for you Time.

Comment: Also I am trying to understand, will u be able to explain in words at high level, if you have time, how you converted my piece of code to yours.

Comment: In truth I didn't look at your code much, I spent more time thinking about the task and realized that there are 2 branches that need to be combined: all the combinations that use the current head of the list, and all the combinations that don't. That's the final `else` clause. If the `level` has dropped down to 1 then the only thing to do is add one more element to the accumulator, submit it to the output list, and iterate to the next item on the input list. That's the `if else` clause. If the input list is empty then there's nothing to be done. Throw away whatever is in the accumulator.